# How to get selected table cell in in Table JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How to get selected table cell in in Table JavaScript without using jQuery?
With jQuery decision is very simple, but in JavaScript without jQuery - I don't know how.
I have table:

```
<table><tr onmouseover="toolnote(this)"><td><td><td></tr></table>
```

I need to bind "onmouseover" event to every cell in table, but if write this event to every cell it will be very unreadable. It follows that I must bind "onmouseover" to tag  through the child and there determine the selected cell. But I do't lnow how get the child index.

JS Code:

```
function toolnote(el){
    var tt = el.getElementsByTagName('td')
    alert(tt[0].innerHTML);
}
```

In this sample event binding to 0-index.

Anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Doubt!

1. You have `toolnote()` as the function name and you are calling `tooltip()` on the element. Is this a typo?
2. You are missing a `;` in the statement.

---

#### Simple Change:

```
function toolnote(el){
    var tt = el.getElementsByTagName('td'); // «--- You are missing a ;
    alert(tt[0].innerText);
}
```

---

#### Or, if you use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), then it is still easier.

```
function toolnote(el){
    alert($(el).children("td").first().text());
}
```

---

#### You need this in each cell, then:

```
<tr><td onmouseover="toolnote(this)"></td><td onmouseover="toolnote(this)"></td><td onmouseover="toolnote(this)"></td></tr>
```

Make the JavaScript this way:

```
function toolnote(el){
    alert(this.innerText);
}
```

In case of **Firefox**:

```
function toolnote(el){
    alert(this.textContent);
}
```

And this is the reason, I said it will be better to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), as it handles this cross browser scripting issue, in a better way.

---

#### In a Single Line:

```
function toolnote(el) {
    var e = el.getElementsByTagName("td");
    if (e.textContent)
        for (i = 0; i < e.length; i++) e[i].onclick = function () {
            alert(this.textContent); // Firefox
        }
    else
        for (i = 0; i < e.length; i++) e[i].onclick = function () {
            alert(this.innerText); // IE
        }
}
```

Comment: You like bold text don't you?^^

Comment: I know jQuery is easier. But how can do that in JavaScript?

Comment: @Leo Check out the **Doubt!** section and reply me. `:)`

Comment: about function calling - yeap, that is typo.)

Comment: Ok, typo fixed. But, main problem - how get the cell index?

Comment: Now what is the problem. You have given `td[0]`, so it is binding to 0th index.

Comment: if "td[0]" - event binding to td[0]. But I need bind event "mouseover" to every cell (tag <td>).

Comment: Okay, got your issue. Wait. In that case, you need to bind the mouseover to the `td`, not the `tr` right?

Comment: // «--- You are missing a ;
I't missed but works. It's no so big problem.
Well, I need help in follow:
how can I get child[index] of cell (it's tag <td>) when the mouse is over a cell?
Also I can write like this: <tr><td onmouseover="toolnote(this)"></td><td onmouseover="toolnote(this)"></td><td onmouseover="toolnote(this)"></td></tr> But it's will be unreadable. How can I replace this code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20316/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-leo)

Answer (score 0):

in the tr call onload="setUpToolnote(this);"

```
function toolnote(){
     alert(this.innerText);
}
function setUpToolnote(el){
 var tt=el.getElementsByTagName('td'); 
for(var i=0;i<tt.length;i++){
tt[i].addEventListener("mouseover", toolnote);
}
}
```